# How to handle encoding inside ProcessBuilder commands?

Tags: java, linux, unicode, character-encoding

A very similar question was posted five years ago at coderanch, but didn't get any answer: http://www.coderanch.com/t/463055/java-io/java/handle-charset-ProcessBuilder

Here is my code:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo тест | hexdump").start();
```

Here is what I'm expecting:

```
0000000 d1 82 d0 b5 d1 81 d1 82
```

This is what I'm getting on another Linux machine:

```
0000000 f2 e5 f1 f2
```

What is it? How to resolve?

Comment: do you encounter the same problem when using [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html) ?

Comment: The first is 16 bit encoding and another one is clearly 8 bit. What does `locale` command print on both machines?

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur `locale` says `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` on the first machine and `LANG=` on the second

Comment: It seems that Java is properly encoding the string using the provided locale. The difference maybe caused by non-unicode locale setting on the second machine. If you want the other machine to use the same encoding try setting up unicode support and set locale to xx_YY.UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding in `ProcessBuilder` refers to the `file.encoding` system property.

For example, when you have the following source:

```java
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo -n тест | hexdump -C");
        Process p = pb.start();
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        printInputStream(is);
        p.waitFor();
    }

    public static void printInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            for (;;) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null) break;
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

You will get `f2 e5 f1 f2` if the encoding like `Windows-1251` is the default encoding in your runtime environment (or you have set `Windows-1251` to `file.encoding` explicitly).

```
$ java -Dfile.encoding=Windows-1251 Main
00000000  f2 e5 f1 f2                                       |....|
00000004
```

You should set `UTF-8` to `file.encoding` explicitly if you want to get `d1 82 d0 b5 d1 81 d1 82` as a result.

```
$ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Main
00000000  d1 82 d0 b5 d1 81 d1 82                           |........|
00000008
```